# Bootstrap 4 beta Nav auto expended

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

I have a navigation from bootstrap 4 Beta.When used in the mobile view or sm view the menu is expanded it does not collapse even after clicking the menu button.If clicked on menu buttons it just re-expands.

```css
#nav ul li a {
 color: white;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
 color: orangered;
}
#nav ul li a:active {
 color: orangered;
 border-top: 2px solid orangered;
 text-decoration: none
}
.navbar-brand {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Something New</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg" id="nav"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span style="color: orangered;letter-spacing: 1px">Tech</span> DudeZ</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container-fluid" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-weight: bold">
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Work</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by removing container-fluid from the div.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg" id="nav"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span style="color: orangered;letter-spacing: 1px">Tech</span> DudeZ</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" style="font-weight: bold">
      <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Our Work</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a> </li>
      <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```